# MongoDB search with multiple keywords and sorted result

Tags: java, mongodb, search, text, search-engine

I have mongo documents which contains data about employees in an organization. 
I wanted to search the documents with multiple keywords and get better result.

```
    eg:**search with "Java, Spring, Hibernate, HTML"** 

should return documents which contains whole keywords and with maximum
number of keywords and so on until it reaches with at least any of the keyword.
Please help me to solve this problem.
```

Answer (score 0):

Give a try to:

```
 db.collection_name.find("text", {search:"Java spring hibernate html"})
```

$text performs a text search on the content of the fields indexed with a text index. A $text expression has the following syntax:

Changed in version 3.2.

```
{
$text:
{
  $search: <string>,
  $language: <string>,
  $caseSensitive: <boolean>,
  $diacriticSensitive: <boolean>
  }
}
```

Remember, this will return documents who match even a single term like only java or html.

Comment: Thanks for the answer. I got it but I need to know if there any way to find document with whole content if not then at least 3 keywords, then 2, then 1 etc

Comment: Yes, this method will find documents with even one keyword and with all or less. The search method will return documents with either Java or spring or hibernate or html or even 2 keywords or more. Try using it once.